# rsync is copying files that already exist on destination

Tags: rsync

Rsync is copying files that exist at the destination. When I run it with `--itemize-changes` this is the prefix on 99% of the files.

```
>f..T......
```

I've attempted to ignore everything with the following flags:

`rsync 
  --itemize-changes 
  --compress 
  --ignore-times
  --no-times
  --no-perms
  --no-owner
  --no-group
  --recursive
  --delete
  --exclude='.git'
  source destination`

`T` is time so why wouldn't `--no-times` cause rsync to skip these files?

Comment: A t means the modification time is different and is being updated to the sender’s value (requires --times). An alternate value of *T* means that the modification time will be set to the transfer time, which happens when a file/symlink/device is updated without --times and when a symlink is changed and the receiver can’t set its time. (Note: when using an rsync 3.0.0 client, you might see the s flag combined with t instead of the proper T flag for this time-setting failure.)

Comment: A . means that the item is not being updated (though it might have attributes that are being modified).